# How do I find IDs of a elements I found with class name (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have stored a list of elements using class

`items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-6 post')`

However, I was wondering if I could find the ID of each one of these elements.

I use Python and am using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IDs of the elements you found using `get_attribute("id")` which is a `WebElement` function:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-6 post')

for item in items:
     print(item.get_attribute("id"))
```